# Configuring NLog programmatically for a C# DLL

Tags: c#, nlog

I am trying to port my code over from using `SimpleLogger` to `NLog`. And I have a snag list of issues. I have only used `NLog` once, and when I did it was for a visual Basic console application.

This project is a C# DLL and I have used the constructor to configure `NLog`:

```
private NLog.Logger _Logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

public MSAToolsLibraryClass()
{
    try
    {
        var config = new NLog.Config.LoggingConfiguration();

        var logfile = new NLog.Targets.FileTarget("logfile")
        {
            FileName = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\test-google-log.txt",
            Layout = "${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message:withException=true:exceptionSeparator=|}"
        };
        var logconsole = new NLog.Targets.ConsoleTarget("logconsole");

        config.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, logconsole);
        config.AddRule(LogLevel.Debug, LogLevel.Fatal, logfile);

        NLog.LogManager.Configuration = config;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _Logger.Error(ex, "Init");
    }

    // NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

1. Is the constructor a good place to do the confliguration of `NLog`?
2. What is the right way to handle the `NLog.LogManager.Shutdown()`?

Comment: Does the dll know by itself somehow when its no longer used? Presumably not. If logging should be bound to the MSAToolsLibraryClass lifetime then make the class disposable and put that call in Dispose. Then the user of that class can call it at the correct time.

Comment: Usually it is the application that decide what NLog configuration to use, and not the individual sub-component. If having a plugin-system where each plugin should have their own isolated LogFactory then see this: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configure-component-logging Alternative one can introduce a shared common-logging-component that is referenced by the individual sub-components and the application-project to get the default NLog-configuration. The shared-common-logging-component could also just be a wellknown `NLog.config`-file, that will be auto-loaded by `LogManager.GetLogger()`.

Comment: @RolfKristensen Thanks. I have always struggled with this concept. At the moment most of the supporting tools use `SimpleLogger`  and write to a log in each tools sub-folder. So I was going to adapt the same. It has not been clear to me how to have my MFC C++ main app, two sub console apps and two dll com libs all work via a single log factory. So I have kept each separate for now. At the moment I am adding a public StartLogging and End logging. Although the formet used to make each text file with todays date as part of the file name.

Comment: @RolfKristensen Only other issue I have write now is not to access my `_Logger` from other classes in the C# DLL. Since it is private to the main parent class at the moment.